# URL to open Compose mail in new window with Unity Mail

Tags: unity, chromium, gmail

I use the "Unity Mail" app, and it does what i need. It's a really nice app.

But there's a thing i can't figure out.

I have made a custom URL in "Compose" in the preferences, so that instead of opening gmail with a new compose mail in the corner, I get an new clean tap with only the new compose mail.
https://mail.google.com/mail/?ui=2&view=cm&fs=1&tf=1&shva=1

The question are, what piece of code do i need to ad, to make it open in a new separate window instead of a new tap? -and possible in a predefined size?

[image]

I use Chromium, but firefox behaves the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asked at launchpad:

Exec:chromium-browser --new-window 'https://mail.google.com/mail/?ui=2&view=cm&fs=1&tf=1&shva=1'